# Rails Model / Migrate Issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dbmigrate

I am reading this book "RailSpace" and am trying to learn rails. However I have been stuck for 2 days on this particular issue.

I've made a user model but when I go to migrate it I keep getting errors. Here's the code I have.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column :screen_name, :string
     t.column :email, :string
     t.column :password, :string
    end
  end

  def self.down
   drop_table :users
  end
end
```

---

**It keeps telling me**

```
rake aborted!
== 1 CreateUsers: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:users)
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `screen_name` varchar(255), `email` varchar(255), `password` varchar(255)) ENGINE=InnoDB/Users/coreyholmes/RubymineProjects/worklink/db/migrate/001_create_users.rb:4:in `up'
-e:1:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `screen_name` varchar(255), `email` varchar(255), `password` varchar(255)) ENGINE=InnoDB
/Users/coreyholmes/RubymineProjects/worklink/db/migrate/001_create_users.rb:4:in `up'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists
/Users/coreyholmes/RubymineProjects/worklink/db/migrate/001_create_users.rb:4:in `up'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Everything? I really want to learn Rails haha.

Comment: Do you have a duplicate migration which may also be creating a `users` table? Have you tried resetting your database totally with `rake db:drop` `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you're trying to create a table `users` that already exists. Is this the only migration you have? If not, make sure you didn't create `users` in a previous migration. Also, check your config/database.yml file to ensure that your development database name is correct.

If this is your first migration, you're probably using a database that already has data in it. Assuming its a development database, you should be able to drop it, i.e. destroy it, and create it from scratch. You can drop your database, create it anew, and run migrations with:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been doing the db:drop & db:migrate but had been forgetting to do the db:create in between :)